# Need help wrapping my head around "this" and console.assert

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I encountered this JS es6 challenge: 
I need to replace "someName" so this code pass provided assert.
Code provided:

```
class myChallenge {
    /**
     * Assert #1
     */
    constructor() {
        let a = 0;
        this['someName'] = () => a +++ a;
    }
}
```

I can change "someName" only. Nothing else. Not even a ' ' around it.
I cannot add or remove anithing else in this class at all.
I cannot change assert in any way.

This is the assert:

```
let inst = new myChallenge();
console.assert(
    inst == 1 && inst == 3 && inst == 5
);
```

I figured that +++ in JS would be compiled as

```
a+1 + a
```

but I have no idea how to equal an object inst to a number

nor do I know how to call this function.
Interesting challenge for those of you more experienced in CodeWars!

I've tried replacing "someName" with all kind of wierd stuff like "this", "inst" or "()" or even "". As expected this just create a key on the object. assert still failed

Comment: `myChallenge.prototype.toString = function () { return this.someName(); }`

Comment: Thanks, @Keith that will work if I can add new line of code before the assert. But the only thing I can do is to replace -- someName --. No new code. That's the point

Comment: `this['toString'] = () => a +++ a;`

Comment: Appreciate your help @Keith. For me this is one of those times when it works but I have no idea why!

Comment: No problem, can you see what's happening here now?.

Comment: Yes, and in Javascript every object has a kind of virtual method called `toString` that you can replace.  as a default an object `toString` will just return `[object Object]`, all we have done here is make it return the value of a, that every time is called get increased again.   And because javascript will evaluate the expression from left to right, unless brackets are used, it will then return `"1"`, then `"3"` and finally `"5"`,  and because only `==` and not `===` for equalitly has been used `1 == "1"` will return true etc.

Comment: inst is an instance of myChallenge - an object. Inst now have a method "toString", which returns the function. As soon as I create an instance of myChallenge - constructor gets called and toString gets executed. If I console.log inst I see the following as expected: myChallenge { toString: [Function] }. I suppose assert pass besause each time we check inst - it is called again and it changes value. I suppose if the assert is inst ==1 && inst ==5 && inst ==3 then it would fail. However how exactly an object now is equal to a number - that I don't know

Comment: @Keith Thank you for such a thorough explanation! I see it now. I didn't realize the part about build-in toString method and that we are just overriding it . Now I get it!